# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter not updated after new firestore query

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `FloatingSearchView` in my app to perform some query on my Firestore database. When I check the size of each query, the result is as expected but my view is not updating with the result. I don't understand if this is the queries or if this is how I handle the different adapter.

I have one `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` for each query. I don't understand what's wrong. Thank you for your help!

```
    floatingSearchView.setOnSearchListener(new 
       FloatingSearchView.OnSearchListener() {


        @Override
                    public void onSuggestionClicked(SearchSuggestion 
           searchSuggestion) {

           mLastQuery = searchSuggestion.getBody();

                    com.google.firebase.firestore.Query qSuggestion =
                            db
                                    .collection("article")
                                    .whereEqualTo("category", category_key)
                                    .whereEqualTo("type", mLastQuery);

                    qSuggestion
                            .get()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new 
        OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot 
        documentSnapshots) {
                                    int size = documentSnapshots
                                            .getDocuments()
                                            .size();
                                    Toast.makeText(Blog.this, "size " + size, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Blog_model> opt = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog_model>()
                            .setQuery(qSuggestion, Blog_model.class)
                            .build();

                    Log.d("option", opt.getSnapshots().toString());

                    suggestionAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Blog_model, Blog.BlogViewHolder>(opt) {
                        @Override
                        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Blog.BlogViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Blog_model model) {
                            holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                            holder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                            holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getPicture());

                            final String post_key = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();

                            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    // Ordinary Intent for launching a new activity
                                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Blog.this, BlogDetails.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("article_id", post_key);
                                    intent.putExtra("category_key", category_key);
                                    intent.putExtra("image", model.getPicture());
                                    intent.putExtra("title", model.getTitle());

                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Blog.BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                            // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
                            // layout called R.layout.message for each item
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                                    .inflate(R.layout.blog_row, group, false);

                            return new Blog.BlogViewHolder(view);
                        }
                    };

                    floatingSearchView.clearSearchFocus();

                    mBlogList.setAdapter(suggestionAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onSearchAction(String currentQuery) {

                    mLastQuery = currentQuery;

                    // query to firebase

                    com.google.firebase.firestore.Query qSuggestion =
                            db
                                    .collection("article")
                                    .whereEqualTo("keyword."+mLastQuery, true);

                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Blog_model> options1 = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog_model>()
                            .setQuery(qSuggestion, Blog_model.class)
                            .build();

                    Log.d("option", options1.getSnapshots().toString());

                    searchAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Blog_model, Blog.BlogViewHolder>(options1) {
                        @Override
                        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Blog.BlogViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Blog_model model) {
                            holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                            holder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                            holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getPicture());

                            final String post_key = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();

                            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
    //                        Toast.makeText(Blog.this, "title", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    // Ordinary Intent for launching a new activity
                                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Blog.this, BlogDetails.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("article_id", post_key);
                                    intent.putExtra("category_key", category_key);
                                    intent.putExtra("image", model.getPicture());
                                    intent.putExtra("title", model.getTitle());

                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Blog.BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                            // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
                            // layout called R.layout.message for each item
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                                    .inflate(R.layout.blog_row, group, false);

                            return new Blog.BlogViewHolder(view);
                        }
                    };

                    mBlogList.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                }
            });


   @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
        if(suggestionAdapter != null){
            suggestionAdapter.startListening();
        }
        if(searchAdapter != null){
            searchAdapter.startListening();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
        if(suggestionAdapter != null){
            suggestionAdapter.stopListening();
        }
        if(searchAdapter != null){
            searchAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `mLastQuery`?

Comment: It depends. If I'm in onSuggestionClicked it is the value of some suggestion and if I'm in onSearchAction it is the value entered by the user

Comment: So when you fist open the activity it does have a value or is `null`?

Comment: Null. The user should click on a suggestion or enter his proper value to fill mLastQuery.

Comment: Yes null until the user enter something or click on a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` objects, which is correct, but the problem in your code is that you are not listening to the second adapter for changes in the right place. To solve this, add inside `onSearchAction` method:

```
searchAdapter.startListening();
```

Right after you create the adapter object. This means that for every character that you type in your `FloatingSearchView`, you create a new adapter and you populate it with the results that are coming from the database. If you are starting listening in the `onStart` method, it doesn't help you at all.